# How to populate or get others collection data in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to get the restaurantOffer collection data when query restaurant data .

**Here is my database Model**

**Restaurant.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const restaurantSchema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     phone: String
 },
 {
     toJSON: { virtuals: true },
     toObject: { virtuals: true },
 },
 { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema);
```

**Offer.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const RestaurantOffer = new Schema({
     offerType: String,
     offerDetails: [String],
     restaurant: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Restaurant", required: true}
 },
 { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('RestaurantOffer', restaurantSchema);
```

Now i want to query restaurant data and each restaurant will returant another filed with restaurantOffer data.

```
let restaurantWithOffer = await Restaurant.find();

res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: restaurantWithOffer });
```

**Above one for sample. Now i want the response like this below**

```
{
    _id: 5e5976099b8f3737907bcc7e,
     name: "Restaurant Name 1",
     phone: "0123456789",
     offer:{
      id: '5e5976099b8f3737907bcc7e',
      OfferType: "OfferType",
      offerDetails: []
     }
},
{
    _id: 5e5976099b8f3737907bcc7e,
     name: "Restaurant Name 2",
     phone: "0123456789",
     offer:{
      id: '5e5976099b8f3737907bcc7e',
      OfferType: "OfferType",
      offerDetails: []
     }
},
{
    _id: 5e5976099b8f3737907bcc7e,
     name: "Restaurant Name 3",
     phone: "0123456789",
     offer:{
      id: '5e5976099b8f3737907bcc7e',
      OfferType: "OfferType",
      offerDetails: []
     }
},
```

Comment: You have a few options. One of them could be: Add `offer: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "RestaurantOffer"}` and save offer id in Restaurant collection. Then use  `Restaurant.find().populate('offer');` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: This way not works. Coz in restaurant offer table dont have the id as reference. so its one way . Only RestaurantOffer collection have the restaurant id as reference, but restaurant collection dont have any ref for offer. Hope you got it

Comment: You can add virtual field

Comment: How i can add virtual filed can you tell me. Please thanks in advance

Comment: check my answer, Let me know if you get any error

Answer (score 0):

```
First change your offer js with this code .
```

**Offer.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const restaurantOfferSchema = new Schema({
     offerType: String,
     offerDetails: [String],
     restaurant_id: {type: String, required: true}
 },
 { timestamps: true }
);


restaurantOfferSchema.virtual('restaurant', {
  ref: 'Restaurant',
  localField: 'restaurant_id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('RestaurantOffer', restaurantOfferSchema);
```

**Change your query as mentioned**

```
Restaurant.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "RestaurantOffer",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "restaurant",
         as: "RestaurantOffer"
       }
  }
])
```

Comment: Its returns the filed with response but empty array , data is empty

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mentioned that your have to update your old record.
Store only string in registered_id field instead of object id

Add new record and check.